# Git hooks - ./gradlew test works on Mac but doesn't work on Windows

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, githooks, gradlew

I need to write a pre-push hook that starts tests on pre-push (gradlew test). 
And it works on mac with **./gradlew test** while on windows it fails. 
On Windows, it works with **gradlew test**.

Our team uses both Windows and Mac OS. 
How can I put both cases in the pre-push hook, so that it works on both OS-es.

Right now my hook looks like this:

```
echo "Starting pre push hook..."

# run the tests 
./gradlew testDebugUnitTest

# store the exit code in a RESULT
RESULT=$?

# return result
exit $RESULT
```